# can we use ''adverbs of frequency'' with other ''expressions of frequency''?

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, adverbs

I know it's odd but I've been wondering if we can use adverbs of frequency with other expressions like once a week or twice a month.  Examples:

> I often go swimming twice a month.
>
> I hardly ever go shopping every day.

what about these situations:

> I take a shower every day
>
> oh, really. I hardly ever take a shower every day ( I want to say that there are conditions that I take a shower every day but It hardly ever happens)

Comment: It makes about as much sense as *I often go swimming rarely*. You'd need a very rare context: *I've hardly ever gone shopping every day for an entire week.*

Comment: @TRomano I've seen this. -How often do you have your hair cut? – Usually once a month, but sometimes twice a month.

Comment: That's not the same thing as your question.  **How often?** means **How frequently?** The answer could be "never".  **often** alone means **frequently**.

Comment: "I usually don't shop every day." "I usually don't shower every day." "Rarely" can replace "usually don't." Note that "shop" and "shower" are verbs that can stand on their own, if you prefer.

Comment: @Mark Hubbard: Idiomatic would be "I don't usually shower every day", not "I usually don't shower every day".

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's fine to create expressions like that, or at least it's perfectly grammatical.  However, I think it's not that common in any language, because it can be confusing.

Once in a while it makes sense:

> If you are paid bi-weekly (once every two weeks), you receive two paychecks each month.  However, twice a year, you receive a paycheck three times each month.

There are better ways to say this, of course, but this sentence should still be understandable.

Comment: I've found ''We usually go swimming twice a month'' in the link below. It's not common?    http://learnenglishteens.britishcouncil.org/grammar-vocabulary/grammar-videos/adverbs-frequency

Comment: It seems an awkward way to say it, but it's understandable.

Comment: Thank you, Andrew. How can I say this? I want to say '' I go shopping twice a week but there are weeks that I don't go shopping at all''. I put often to convey my point but that makes it awkward. what should I say?

Comment: "Most of the time I go shopping twice a week."   This implies that there are weeks when you don't.  If it's important enough you can be specific, "occasionally I shop once per week, and rarely not at all."

Comment: **Usually** is not the same thing as **often**, Masih K.

Comment: "If you are paid every two weeks, you will normally *average* two paychecks a month. However, twice a year, you will receive three paychecks during a calendar month, as there are 52 weeks and thus 26 pay periods a year." Not, X"However, twice a year, you receive a paycheck three times *each* month." "During those months" would work.

Comment: @TRomano you're saying that ''often'' and ''usually'' can't be replaced in a sentence like ''I often/usually go shopping once a week?''

Comment: @Masih K. I'm saying that **often** and **usually** are not perfect synonyms. They mean different things.  You do not **often** have your hair cut once a month.  You **usually** have your hair cut once a month. *How often do you have your hair cut? -- Usually once a month.* That can be paraphrased:  How frequently do you have your hair cut? --  My regular practice is to have it cut once a month, with an exception now and then.